# Why Doesn't the Fetch API Call My API Endpoint I Created in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, fetch-api

I am wondering why the Fetch API in javascript isn't call the endpoint I created in express. When I start my server and go to the '/characters' endpoint, it returns correctly formatted JSON.

Here is my express index.js

```
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

const charactersRoute = require('./routes/characters');

//Characters Route
app.use('/characters', charactersRoute)

app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Here is my Characters Route

```
const express = require('express'); // Web Framework
const https = require('https');
const router = express.Router();
const PORT = 3000;

// app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
//     if(err) console.log(err);
//     console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
// })

const api = 'https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters/?limit=20';

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    https.get(api, (response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        
        response.on('data', (d) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(d);
            res.send(data);
        })

        // res.send("Running")
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my Characters.jsx file where I'm using Fetch

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Character() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/characters')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setData(data))
            // console.log(data);
    }, []);


}
```

When I run my front end and check the response I receive, it returns my index.html.
If I fetch the API URL itself, then it correctly returns the JSON in my frontend. But When I try to fetch the API endpoint I created in express, I don't get any data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `res => console.log(res)` can you try `res => res.json()`?

Comment: Can you inspect the console and show us the error? Did you receive a 404 error or something else?

Comment: @IrfanullahJan Yes that was what I was originally trying, but wouldn't work. Sorry, I was logging the response I got and forgot to switch it back when I posted this question.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh 
I am getting an "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error which I why I believe I am receiving some html as my response.

Comment: In the network tabs, you can search for the request `/characters` and see what you receive from the server :) It can help you debug :)

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh Yup, I checked and it looks like I am getting an HTML file as a response. This is where the confusion starts. The URL for my response is "http://localhost:3000/characters" which is returning that html file. But I created an endpoint "/characters" to return JSON.

Comment: I'd add `return <>{data}</>` at the end of `Character` to make sure you don't just ignore the fetched data.

Comment: Can you check the console of the backend app to make sure it's running?  Which port does your backend/frontend run on? Recall that 2 applications cannot run on the same port.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh The backend is running on port 3000 and the front end is running on port 3001. The response URL I get from the frontend is "localhost:3001/characters" which doesn't return any data. But when I go to "localhost:3000/characters" it returns the correct JSON

Comment: Glad you found it :) You should use an absolute URL instead of the relative one. I give some more detail in my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not set the endpoint for the fetch function. It doesn't know what API '/characters' is. It is similar to saying the house number but not telling the street, you don't know where to go. So you need to pass the absolute path to fetch to request data from the server, because the server is a different 'entity', it's not the same with your front-end. Therefore, you need to provide the full API URL. Or, if using axios, since I see you imported it above, you must set `axios.defaults.baseURL = <API_URL>`, (or provide the full URL in the request itself just like in `fetch`) and then make the request with the help of axios, not fetch.

Therefore your React code will look a little something like this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export default function Character() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   const getData = async () => {
       try {
          const {data} = await axios.get('/characters');
          setData(data);
       } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
       }
     };

    getData();
}, []);


}
```

But I suggest you create a different file with all the axios requests and there you set the `baseUrl` - that's a better practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think is that you are not using [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in your app.

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
```

Try this, I hope it helps you!

Comment: This didn't seem the fix the problem, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

**Error pattern**

This kind of error occurs when we send a request from the client-side to the server-side using a relative URL (`/characters` in this case). But the frontend app and the backend app run on 2 different ports.

**Reason**

When we use relative URLs, the URL will be **concatenated** with the current host (the frontend host, not the backend). Usually, we receive a 404 error because the resource doesn't exist.

**Example**

Backend Express app running on port 5000. React app running on port 3000 for development. In React app, if we send a request to `/users`, then the full URL is `http://localhost:3000/users`. The request goes to the React app, not the backend server. And we don't receive the desired output.

**Action**

You should use an absolute URL, something like: `http://localhost:5000/users` to send the request to your backend app. Consider saving the host part (`http://localhost:5000`) in a global variable in order to use it in multiple places in your frontend code. When you have different environments for the backend (DEV/STAGING/PRODUCTION), you can change the backend host in only 1 place.